# Вывод поста в виде Grid на Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, вёрстка

Такая задача. И есть два варианта для реализации. _CMS Wordpress.

[image: Блок новостей]

1. Можно создать один блок и опубликовать только `Новость 1` и во втором блоке можно исключить `Новость 1` и начиная с `Новость 2` вывести остальное.

Вопрос: Как на втором wrapper-е исключить `Новость 1`?

2. Можно вывести в виде *Grid*.

Вопрос: какие стили нужно использовать для такого вывода с фиксированной шириной?

Comment: Это два разных вопроса. Раздели их. А для первого дай код, как у тебя выводиться.

Comment: Лучше через второй способ. Как создать именно такой Grid блок (как на схеме)?

Comment: Ешё раз -  исправь вопрос и определись что тебе нужно

Comment: Адаптивную верстку таких вещей делают следующим образом. Есть две колонки - под Новость1 и под все остальное, в сумме 100% ширины. В правой колонке делают 6 вложенных колонок, по 33% каждая. Все это выводится одним циклом после WP_Query.